# Dynamically create bootstrap tooltip for fields that are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write jquery script that lets me create tooltips for select fields that doesn't have value in it. My requirement is that it has to create tooltip dynamically in my js code , meaning it should run without writing the attributes "data-toggle" , "data-placment" and "title" in the html code.

The problem is that bootstrap tooltip seems to ignore attributes that are dynamically created. I tried manually writing the attributes for tooltip in the html code and it works fine , but once I change it to code below It just don't work.

Here is my code so far. Pardon if the indention is hard to understand.

```
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery('[id*=form_fields_]').each(function(index, value)
    {
        if (jQuery(this).prop("tagName") == "SELECT" && jQuery(this).val() == "")
        {
            jQuery(this).data('toggle', 'tooltip');
            jQuery(this).data('placement', 'right');
            jQuery(this).attr('title', 'Please select an item');
            jQuery(this).tooltip(
            {
                container: 'body'
            });
            jQuery(this).tooltip();
            jQuery(this).on("hidden.bs.tooltip", function()
            {
                jQuery(this).css("display", "");
                jQuery(this).tooltip('disable');
            });
        }
    });
    jQuery('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip('show');
});
```

Comment: have you checked it using inspect element if tooltips are added?

Comment: Checked and no tooltip has been added. The problem is that I dynamically added the attributes needed for initializing bootstrap tooltip. I can make the above code work by removing the 3 lines that adds attributes and manually place it in my html code.

Comment: can you please add a working fiddle? And see the answer below from Ikkun. I thinks that answers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery('[id*=form_fields_]').each(function()
    {
        if (jQuery(this).val().length <=0)
        {
            jQuery(this).data('toggle', 'tooltip');
            jQuery(this).data('placement', 'bottom');
            jQuery(this).attr('title', 'Please select an item');
            jQuery(this).tooltip(
            {
                container: 'body'
            });
        }
        jQuery(this).keyup(function()
        {
                console.log(jQuery(this).val().length);
            if (jQuery(this).val().length <=0)
            {
                jQuery(this).data('toggle', 'tooltip');
                jQuery(this).data('placement', 'bottom');
                jQuery(this).attr('title', 'Please select an item');
                jQuery(this).tooltip(
                {
                    container: 'body'
                });
                if(jQuery(this).focus()){
                    jQuery(this).tooltip(
                    {
                        container: 'body'
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery(this).tooltip('destroy');     
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qekg2zpm/12/

Comment: When empty it returns 0. So pretty much working, or your point is something else?